# how to convert Arabic numbers to English numbers in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

in my app, I have 5 uitextfields. My intended users are Arabic speakers so when they use my app, they will either insert number in English or in Arabic.

The app works just fine with English numbers. However, when I run it and insert numbers in Arabic, the app deals with the textfields as if they all were empty and gives the answer as 0

How can I make sure that the textfields are not nill AND a double, whithout ignoring Arabic numbers?

This is the code inside the "calButton" function:

```
     /*let value1 = Double(income.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value2 = Double(salaries.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value3 = Double(tools.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value4 = Double(maintinance.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let value5 = Double(otherExpenses.text ?? "") ?? 0
    let sum = value1 - ( value2 + value3 + value4 + value5)

    print("result is: \(sum)")*/



    let textFields = [income, salaries, tools, maintinance, otherExpenses]
    var sum = 0.0
    for textField in textFields {
        if let number = Double((textField?.text!)!) { //checks that it is not nil AND a Double
            sum += number
        }
    }

    expensesTotal.text = String(sum)
    // print("result is: \(sum)")
```

Comment: Use a dictionary which it keys is arabic numbers, and the values is english numbers.

Comment: The `Double` initializer is very simplistic. For this sort of complex behaviour you'll want to use `NumberFormatter` https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter

Comment: "Arabic numbers" are the decimal system we use everyday. Perhaps you meant "converting Arabic strings to decimal numbers"? And can you provide some example input and output?

Comment: well, when I input ١، ٣،٤ ،٥ as an example, the result is 0.0. But, when i input 1,3,4,5 the result is 13.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to convert the arabic number string to english first and then do the calculation part.

```
    let numberStr: String = "٨٦٩١٢٨٨١"
    let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "EN") as Locale!
    let final = formatter.number(from: numberStr)
    let doubleNumber = Double(final!)
    print("\(doubleNumber)")
```

Comment: What about arabic decimal value? Do you have any solution for arabic decimal value to English number conversion?

Comment: does not work for large number like: 123456789012345678901234

Comment: Is there any possible way to convert numbers to Arabic Number?

Comment: if you have a number that starts with 0 this method will not help you. It will remove the first zero.  For other numbers, it works fine.

Answer (score 18):

## From Any language, To Any Language

You can convert digits from ***ANY* language** to **ANY other language** in a single line code like:

```
"12345".convertedDigitsToLocale(Locale(identifier: "FA")) /* ۱۲۳۴۵ */

"۱۲۳۴۵".convertedDigitsToLocale(Locale(identifier: "EN")) /* 12345 */
```

with the following extension:

```
extension String {
    private static let formatter = NumberFormatter()

    func clippingCharacters(in characterSet: CharacterSet) -> String {
        components(separatedBy: characterSet).joined()
    }

    func convertedDigitsToLocale(_ locale: Locale = .current) -> String {
        let digits = Set(clippingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted))
        guard !digits.isEmpty else { return self }

        Self.formatter.locale = locale

        let maps: [(original: String, converted: String)] = digits.map {
            let original = String($0)
            let digit = Self.formatter.number(from: original)!
            let localized = Self.formatter.string(from: digit)!
            return (original, localized)
        }

        return maps.reduce(self) { converted, map in
            converted.replacingOccurrences(of: map.original, with: map.converted)
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### The Swift Package

You can find this extension and some more useful extensions with their unit test [**Here on the github**](https://github.com/MojtabaHs/FoundationExtensionKit/blob/master/Sources/StringExtensionKit/ConvertedDigitsToLocale.swift) and use them easily as a Swift package.

Answer (score 9):

Swift-5 solution for all non-Latin string occurrences.

```
extension String {
    var containsNonEnglishNumbers: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && range(of: "[^0-9]", options: .regularExpression) == nil
    }

    var english: String {
        return self.applyingTransform(StringTransform.toLatin, reverse: false) ?? self
    }
}
```

Usage -

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(field:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc func didChangeText(field: UITextField) {
    if ((field.text?.containsNonEnglishNumbers) != nil) {
        field.text = field.text?.english
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome solution

Comment: `applyingTransform(, reverse:)` leaves some underline characters for what character it changes. for example "۱۱۱" becomes "1̱1̱1̱" instead of "111". any solution for this issue?

Comment: Take a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62733983/5623035) @MrAlirezaa

Comment: Thanks @MojtabaHosseini, actually I wanted to fix the issue related to `applyingTransform(_:reverse:)` method of `String` type. The solution is to apply this method two times like this: `applyingTransform(.toLatin, reverse: false)?.applyingTransform(.stripCombiningMarks, reverse: false)`

Answer (score 4):

This will replace any arabic number to english

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField.keyboardType == .numberPad && string != "" {
            let numberStr: String = string
            let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
            if let final = formatter.number(from: numberStr) {
                textField.text =  "\(textField.text ?? "")\(final)"
            }
                return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

dont forget setting the delegate:

yourTextField.delegat = self

Answer (score 1):

I have a simpler solution with String Extension:

```
extension String{
/// To convert Arabic / Persian numbers to English
/// - Returns: returns english number
func changeToEnglish()-> String{
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
    let engNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: self)
    return "\(engNumber!)"
}

/// To convert English numbers to Arabic / Persian
/// - Returns: returns Arabic number
func changeToArabic()-> String{
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "AR")
    let arabicNumber = numberFormatter.number(from: self)
    return "\(arabicNumber!)"
}
```

Comment: Really useful. Thank you.