# How to restrict UITextField input to only accept ENGLISH numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4, arabic

I have a UITextField and most users have an Arabic and English keyboard in there iPhones, so my problem is when i type Arabic number in my text field the app crash but when i enter an English number everything work just fine!

Any help please ..

my code :

```
var ourArray = [Int]()
var forThemArray = [Int]()



@IBOutlet weak var ourTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var forThemTextField: UITextField!




@IBAction func record(_ sender: Any) {


    if ourTextField.hasText == true {
        ourArray.append(Int(ourTextField.text!)!)
    }else{
        let error = UIAlertController(title: "تنبيه !", message: "الرجاء تعبئة الحقول ثم اضغط سجل", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "موافق", style: .default, handler: nil)

        error.addAction(dismiss)
        present(error, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }


    if forThemTextField.hasText == true {
        forThemArray.append(Int(forThemTextField.text!)!)
    }else{
        let error = UIAlertController(title: "تنبيه !", message: "الرجاء تعبئة الحقول ثم اضغط سجل", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "موافق", style: .default, handler: nil)

        error.addAction(dismiss)
        present(error, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return
    }


    //remove the textField input
    ourTextField.text = ""
    forThemTextField.text = ""

    print("Our array is : \(ourArray)")
    print("for them array is : \(forThemArray)")

    tableview.reloadData()

    count()

    self.view.endEditing(true)

    updateImage()



}
```

Comment: Why does your app crash? Why not properly handle the Arabic numbers?

Comment: I don't know, i'm new in swift

Comment: Post relevant code and details about the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy please check the code

Comment: Use NumberFormatter to convert the sting to a number. And don’t force unwrap optionals.

Comment: @rmaddy How can i use NumberFormatter ?

Comment: Look at the documentation and search for examples.

Comment: Thank you for your help , i will look for it

Comment: @rmaddy i can't find a solution for my problem , can you help ?

Comment: Update your question with your attempts to use `NumberFormatter` to convert the string to a number.

Comment: @rmaddy I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668231/how-to-convert-arabic-numbers-to-english-numbers-in-swift) and it works - and I would thank you for opening my mind in these ways such as NumberFormatter .